# C# UWP - Textbox hangs on focus with large amount of text

Tags: c#, textbox, focus, uwp

I am building a universal windows 10 app that enables the user to open plain text files from the file system and display them in a textbox. Normally, this works fine, but now I'm investigating the possibility that the user opens a massive file. For testing, I'm using a file about 11,000 lines long. `FileIO` loads the file into a string in about 1s, and the string is displayed in the textbox almost instantly, but then the app hangs for 6 or 7 seconds, and only after that I can use the textbox normally. After investigating, I found that the app hangs like this every time the textbox is focused or unfocused. So my question is, is this a limitation of UWP, or is there something I'm missing here? If it is an API limitation, that's fine, I'll just need to limit the size of the input file. The reason I'm asking is it just doesn't seem quite right for a textbox to lag the UI like that. Notepad and notepad++ both handle the file fine. Thanks!

---

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="App7.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:App7"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibiliy/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top">Browse</Button>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs 
This is the only addition to the default template

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

    StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null) {
        // Not the issue
        string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

        // This causes the textbox to be focused, or at least has the same effect
        this.TextBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it will solve the problem, but I guess you should try to set TextBlock.Text value using data binding(`{binding}` and `{x:Bind}`) instead of just doing `TextBox.Text="blahblahblah"` from code-behind.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem, and I think I know why. The hang happens on focus or unfocus, and the textbox just happens to focus when the text is changed. Once the text is loaded and the UI has recovered, it will hang again on the next focus event, even if the text in it doesn't change